# how to open a save and open dialogue box with php onclick of a link

Tags: php, web-services

I am working on a php project. I am getting a filename as the response of my webservice.
There is a link i am showing on the page on success of the webservice call.Onclick of the link
i need to open a dialogue box where it will ask the user to save or open the file. On selection of save as, it will save the file in a particular location and if we select open, it will open the file. I am totally unaware as how to do this. Can any body help me out with some examples or any pointers?
Thank you

Comment: Opening dialog by clicking by link is work not for PHP, this is JavaScript work.

Answer (score 0):

the best method would be to just stream the file from PHP, and let the browser show the default save/open dialog.

if you need more advanced behavior, you'll need a lot of javascript.

Comment: if you set the header to match the filetype, you can either use `file_get_contents()` and echo it, or if you have the access, `passthru` ( which is faster ).